# python function to combine many dataset without listing them all

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to write a function to combine over 24 datasets without actually listing them all. Ideally having a function to take in one at a time and combine the previous one. At the end, it accumulates all datasets. I am not sure how to recursively accumulate them. How should I create this function? Thanks.

Comment: So what's your question then?

Answer (score 0):

Initialized a df1, then run the function

```
def add_dataset():
  file = input('enter file')
  return pd.read_excel(file+'.xlsx', sheet_name='Data')

df2= pd.concat([df1, add_dataset()])
```